# How to set property ("xalign") of GtkCellRendered in Glade

Tags: gtk, glade

I understood how to create a ListStore model, a GtkTreeView and how to link them together with Glade.

Now I'd like to set the property "xalign" of one GtkCellRender. It seems I can link the attribute "xalign" to the model (I can set the relevant column in the model that stores the value of "xalign" property for that row).
However I'd like to set "xalign" property to 0.5 value for all the rows.

I was able to have this effect through code:
    self.cellName.set_property("xalign", 0.5)

I'm finding a way to set the property directly in Glade, so I can avoid to write code for that.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the TreeView > Edit > Hiearchy > Select Cell Renderer > Common Properties and Attributes > Horizontal Alightment.